# ProgressDialog to fetch data and images from server to re-size and render them

Tags: android

I have the following requirement:

1. Need to fetch data from server.
2. Re-size multiple images which is fetched from server & render on screen.

**My Approach**

I am using the following code

```
private void fetchResult() {
        mProgressDialogue = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                "Fetching results ... Please wait");
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                try {
                    mResponseVec = new Vector();
                    Object getItemsResponseObj = loadCategoryResponse();
                    mResponseVec = Utilities.getInstance()
                            .parseGetItemsResponse(getItemsResponseObj);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    protected Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            showProduct(mProductName, mResponseVec, mProductId, 0, 0);
            mProgressDialogue.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

Within the `showProduct()` method, I am resizing around 6 images after calling the images `imageUrl`. This resizing of the images is taking some time. The problem I am facing with the above code is that, after fetching the data from the server, during the time for resizing, the progressdialog is visible but it becomes static (stop rotating) & stays on that non rotating position for some time & then the `showProduct` screen is displayed.

My requirement is I want the progressDialog to remain & rotate till the `showScreen` is displayed.

Will be great if anyone can provide their inputs.

Comment: Sounds like something is tying up the UI thread.  The only thing in your code that runs in the UI thread is the `showProduct()` call.  What does this method do?

Comment: The showProduct() has the following functionalities:                                                      i> Fetches 6 images after calling the images using the Imageurl        ii> Resizes the 6 images & displays on the screen .. this resizing of the images is taking some time .. It can be  only an UI thread issue . Any idea how it can be avoided ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you create the messageHandler from your UI thread (assuming fetchResult runs in the UI thread). That binds it to the UI thread and its message queue. So, when your new thread sends a message to the messageHandler, the messageHandler is executed in the UI thread, blocking your progress dialog.

Try splitting up showProduct into one part that does the fetching and resizing, and another part that displays the results. Then move the fetching and resizing part into your thread and send the message to your UI thread only after the resizing has finished. The messageHandler then only has to do the second part, i.e. displaying the images.

Cheers
  tadzio

Comment: yes i vote up really helpful for me same problem and get solution keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted the progress dialog to go away before showProduct(), why did you put the dismiss after it in your code?

Comment: I dont want the progressbar to go before the showProduct().                                                   The showProduct() has the following functionalities: i> Fetches 6 images after calling the images using the Imageurl ii> Resizes the 6 images & displays on the screen .. this resizing of the images is taking some time ........... I want the progressbar to also rotate till all the images are resized & stop before the resized images are displayed on the screen

Comment: ok.. so instead of launching a thread to retrieve the data from server you could start a thread to do the showProduct() and show and dismiss the progressDialog before the start of that thread and after the showProduct()